# special characters french accents

Tags: php, mysql

We are fetching data from csv file through php, and trying to compare data to insert the right data in our database but php comparison is not working as data in file is with french accents.

Here is a piece of code we are working with.

```
if($data[0]=='Expression' && $data[1]=='Domaine (Domain)' &&  utf8_decode($data[2])==utf8_decode('DŽfinition (Definition)') && $data[3]=='Commentaire (Commentary)' && $data[4]=='Voir aussiÉ (See also É)' && $data[5]=='ƒquivalent anglais (English equivalent)' && $data[6]=='En contexte / exemple(s) É (In context / examples)' && $data[7]=='Source' )
     {
                 echo "<tr>
                      <td>".$data['0']."</td>
                      <td>".$data['1']."</td>
                      <td>".$data['2']."</td>
                      <td>".$data['3']."</td>
                      <td>".$data['4']."</td>
                      <td>".$data['5']."</td>
                      <td>".$data['6']."</td>
                      <td>".$data['7']."</td>
                      <td><i class='fa fa-close text-navy'></i></td>
                    </tr>";
         return true;
     }
     else
     {
         echo "invalid data";
         exit;
     }
```

We have tried with this as well.

```
function convert($data)
{
    $value = utf8_encode($data);
    $value = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $value);
    return $value;
}
```

Header is already placed output is fine

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

We have tried with several php functions like utf_decode,html entities, html special char, htmlspecialchar_decode but nothing is working.

```
echo print_r(utf8_decode($data[2]));
```

output is as following:

D?finition (Definition)1invalid data

Actual word is : DŽfinition (Definition)'

We are working on french dictionary and need to do real time searching on the data as well, please help with mysql as well, like which functions are needed to be called before insertion for decoding and which functions are needed to be called before showing data back to user encoding!

Hope my question is bit clear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: your CSV  is in ANSI or UTF8 ?

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: @Melvita it's in ANSI

Comment: then try to convert it in UTF8

Comment: @Melvita How to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the CSV in UTF8, open it in notepad.

And Go to File - Save As

Change the Encoding to UTF-8.

or with Libre Office :

https://csvimproved.com/support/questions-and-answers/916-save-a-csv-file-as-utf-8

Hope it ll help

Comment: Using Mac machine?

Comment: With Libre Office it ll work, source : https://rothmanshore.com/2013/10/29/solved-editing-a-csv-with-utf-8-encoding-on-a-mac/

Comment: When i open it with Libre Office it showing wrong output using UTF-8 

Actual word in csv DŽfinition (Definition)'

Comment: in libre its Définition (Definition)

Comment: so it worked ?  if not try with an code editor like Sublime or Atom, when you save the Csv just check the encodage.